# Unity3D : Prefab Instancing Issue

Tags: c#, unity

I am using latest unity engine and I am having a scripting issue.

I create a prefab , added a few scripts to it and I am trying to instantiate a few of those objects like this :

```
        GameObject go = Instantiate(Prefab) as GameObject;
        var co = go.GetComponent<MyScriptA>();
```

Issue here is co is always null, this means that MyScriptA is no on the go instance.
Accessing the prefab.GetComponent also returns null, but the prefab has the scripts in the editor and its assigned also in the editor to the Prefab variable (drag dropping). So I am not sure what might be wrong.
For example if I Debug.Log(prefab) its not null.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: ok, so if you delete everything in the Hierarchy pane and then drag and drop the prefab from the Project pane to the Hierarchy pane, will it have the scripts?

Comment: It does. All the scripts are there, I even tried creating a prefab with only a particle system (maybe it was a issue on my script) Still the same applys.

Comment: that really doesn't make sense, there must be something else.

Comment: I have been looking everywhere, maybe I did my prefab wrong. 
I just create a object added my script to it, created a prefab dragged the object on top of it, then tried to execute that code, and it says that its always null.
Does anything I said seems like the wrong way to do it?

Comment: no, that's it... and if you dragged into the Hierarchy and you saw in the inspector what you wanted, then it's correct. It must be something in your loading code.

Comment: I'm not sure what happens if you try to instantiate passing null, but are you sure that `Prefab` is not null?

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction, Prefab was not null though.
It was actually being overwritten to a empty game object.

I feel such a dummy :|

Comment: cool. glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GameObject go = Instantiate(Prefab) as GameObject;
```

Since go is a gameobject your prefab must also be a gameobject
Make sure you have something like

```
GameObject prefab;
```

at the start rather than

```
Transform prefab;
```

Comment: Honestly I am not sure What was the issue, but somehow I fixed when I reinstalled Unity + Rewrote most scripts. So I am accepting this as answer because this is actually he correct way.